# ConcurrentMarkSweep GC is over 1307ms

Tags: cassandra, garbage-collection

how to tune CMS gc in my cassandra. we are seeing this happening every hours/ gc sweep taking over a sec
 ConcurrentMarkSweep GC in 1307ms.  CMS Old Gen: 377389368 -> 365877600; Par Eden Space: 588805072 -> 0; Par Survivor Space: 4718504 -> 0

we have Heap setting as follows in env file.

```
MAX_HEAP_SIZE="8192M"
HEAP_NEWSIZE="800M" 

### CMS Settings

-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:SurvivorRatio=8
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000
-XX:+CMSParallelInitialMarkEnabled
-XX:+CMSEdenChunksRecordAlways
# some JVMs will fill up their heap when accessed via JMX, see CASSANDRA-6541
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

Comment: if you're using Java 8, then G1GC could be a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

There is not nearly enough info but decreasing XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction (55) might help if the GC is from fragmentation.

Comment: can you please let me know what other information you need